# How do I look at remote processes in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-3.0

I want to know if a process is running in the current machine as a part of my application ,but my application is deployed in another machine.

I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Getprocessbyname` but it looks for processes on the machine the application is deployed to. I want to know whether the process is running on *my* machine.

Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** This is edited by someone other than the question asker in an attempt to make it easier to understand. I have may not correctly captured their question..

Comment: Change the title of your question, it does not help us to understand your problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("processname", "mymachine");
```